# How to get a long number of metadata tags from AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, metadata, android-manifest

I want to get a sting frome metadata tags, but i can't use metadata.getString(), becauese it returns null. so, i use metadata.getInt(), but i can't get the correct value. How can i do it?`<meta-data android:name="GDT_BANNER_POST_ID" android:value="9079537218417626401"/>`

Comment: instead of android:value="9079537218417626401" use android:value="@string/your_value" and getString() will work

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
ActivityInfo app = getPackageManager().getActivityInfo(this.getComponentName(), PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES|PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
Bundle bundle = ai.metaData;
Object value = (Object)metaData.get(name);
```

Comment: I've tried, it does't work. I got another number, -1531409119……not it.

Comment: instead of android:value="9079537218417626401" use android:value="@string/your_value"

Answer (score 0):

Use a method, such as:

```
    private String retrieveKey(Context aContext, String aKey) {

    // get the key from the manifest 
    final PackageManager pm = aContext.getPackageManager();
    try { 
        final ApplicationInfo info = pm.getApplicationInfo(aContext.getPackageName(),
                PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        if (info.metaData == null) {
            Log.i("Key not found in manifest", aKey);
        } else { 
            final String value = String.valueOf(info.metaData.get(aKey));
            if (value == null) {
                Log.i("Key not found in manifest", aKey);
            } else { 
                return value.trim();
            } 
        } 
    } catch (final PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.i("Key not found in manifest", aKey);
    } 
    return ""; 
}
```

In your manifest, add:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="MY_KEY"
            android:value="MY_VALUES" />
```

In your code, just retrieve it:

```
String myKey = retrieveKey(this, "MY_KEY");
```

Comment: What are you getting ?

Comment: I get a string like "-1531409119".

Comment: Updated my code. Alternatively, note that this line: 
`info.metaData.get(aKey);`
has multiple `getters`, one of them should be retrieving what you need.
Alternatively, if you still can't manage to find a way to get it from the `Manifest`, add it to the `strings` resources.